# ternary operation inside object creation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a traditional conditional statement below, and I was wondering if I could translate this into an inline conditional(ternary?) statement.

```
var type;

if type === 1 {

    $('#form1').append(new mySuperObject({ model: myModelB}).render().$el);

} else {


    $('#form1').append(new mySuperObject({ model: new myModelA({ type: myType.Gas }) }).render().$el);

}
```

Would this be the proper format?

```
$('#form1').append(new mySuperObject({ model: ((type === 1) ? myModelB : new myModelA({ type: myType.Gas) }) }).render().$el);
```

When I try it, I get the error below in Firebug console:

```
TypeError: this.model.get(...) is undefined
```

Thanks

Comment: Ternary operators are better used in one-line expressions; `if..else` looks better in this case.

Comment: The ternary is illegible. The only thing you need in the conditional is the creation of the new `mySuperObject`, too.

Comment: Also, your syntax is wrong. Check here http://jshint.com

Comment: Where are the parentheses that go around the `if` conditional?

Comment: `new myModelA({ type: myType.Gas) }) ` should be `new myModelA({ type: myType.Gas }) )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just have a parenthesis out of place. Compare the two lines below. The first is the orginal.

```
$('#form1').append(new mySuperObject({ model: ((type === 1) ? myModelB : new myModelA({ type: myType.Gas) }) }).render().$el);
$('#form1').append(new mySuperObject({ model: ((type === 1) ? myModelB : new myModelA({ type: myType.Gas })) }).render().$el);
```

To make it easier to read though, you could go with:

```
var model = (type === 1) ? myModelB : new myModelA({ type: myType.Gas });
$('#form1').append(new mySuperObject({ model: model }).render().$el);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors in there..

for readability you could use

```
var objToUse = (type === 1) ? myModelB : new myModelA({ type: myType.Gas});
$('#form1').append(new mySuperObject({ model: objToUse }).render().$el);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't jam all of that stuff together like that.  To avoid the duplication of code, you can do something like this:

```
var type;
var model;

if(type === 1) {

    model = myModelB;

} else {

    model = new myModelA({ type: myType.Gas });

}

$('#form1').append(new mySuperObject({ "model": model}).render().$el);
```

Comment: `model = (type === 1 ? myModelB : new myModelA({ type: myType.Gas });`

Comment: I tend to dislike ternaries for readability unless they're very simple, but that would work as well.

Comment: Agreed. Just figured I would add it. Ternaries that start to get long just end up being confusing. They might look better (1 line?) up front, but you go back and bam... You wish you hadn't xD

Answer (score 1):

The following:

```
if (type === 1) {
    $('#form1').append(new mySuperObject({ model: myModelB}).render().$el);
} else {
    $('#form1').append(new mySuperObject({ model: new myModelA({ type: myType.Gas }) }).render().$el);
}
```

is the same as:

```
 var model;
 if (type === 1) {
     model = myModelB;
 }
 else {
     model = new myModelA({type: myType.Gas});
 }
 $("#form1").append(new mySuperObject({model: model})).render().$el;
```

Which is the same as:

```
 var model = (type === 1) 
             ? myModelB 
             : new myModelA({type: myType.Gas});

 $("#form1").append(new mySuperObject({model: model})).render().$el;
```

And you can jam it together if you really want:

```
 $("#form1").append(new mySuperObject({model: (type === 1) ? myModelB : new myModelA({type: myType.Gas})})).render().$el;
```

I do recommend the second or third variant vs. jamming it all together in one line, though. The functional programmer in me likes the third over the second, actually, because you only have one assignment and don't have to declare the variable separately from assigning it.